# Spring form persist List of composite objects

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-form

guys ! How can i save entity with List of composite type. For example, i have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distributor")
public class Distributor {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Exhibitor> exhibitor = new ArrayList<Exhibitor>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Merchandiser> merchandiser = new ArrayList<Merchandiser>();
```

..getters and setters.

**Submission controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "submission", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSubmission(Model model) {

    Query Exhibitor = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Exhibitor");
    List<Merchandiser> listExhibitor = Exhibitor.getResultList();
    model.addAttribute("listOfExhibitors", listExhibitor);

    Query Merchandisers = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Merchandiser");
    List<Merchandiser> listMerchandisers = Merchandisers.getResultList();
    model.addAttribute("listMerchandisers", listMerchandisers);

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Distributor");
    List<Distributor> listDistributors = query.getResultList();
    model.addAttribute("listDistributors", listDistributors);

    model.addAttribute("submission", new Distributor());

    return "submission";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "submission", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String show(Model model, @ModelAttribute("submission") Distributor submission, BindingResult error) {


    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(submission);

    /*Distributor distributor = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Distributor.class, 1L);*/


    return "redirect:submission";
}
```

and JSP, which is update every time when entity ( Merchandiser or exhibitor or Distributor is updated) The JSP is working now, but how can i update(or put) in **List exhibitor = new ArrayList();** filed, from the jsp form:

```
    <form:select path="name">
        <c:forEach var="distributor" items="${listDistributors}"  >
            <form:option value="${distributor.id}">${distributor.name}</form:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>

    <form:select path="exhibitor">
        <c:forEach var="exhibitors" items="${listOfExhibitors}"  >
            <form:option value="${exhibitors.id}">${exhibitors.name}</form:option>
        </c:forEach>

    </form:select>
<input type="submit" value="Submission" />
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I see an error in code

`List<Merchandiser> listExhibitor = Exhibitor.getResultList();` it should be
`List<Exhibitor> listExhibitor = Exhibitor.getResultList();`.

Second, You are not follwing variable naming convention. variable name should always start with small character.

Third,Your JSP does not seem correct to me. Post full JSP page. Why would you add list of Distributor when you will be saving one Distributor at a time.